# Opus tagging for dynamic contents of an Opus audio webstream

Tags: ogg-opus

I have a question. An important German radio station (state supported) is broadcasting three opus streams. They seem to have issues using tagging with live radio broadcasts. Their tag for their Opus stream is "stream", nothing else, nothing dynamic.

Do you have a suggestion I can relay to them to fix their issue, because they broadcast their tagging of the content what is playing in realtime to their MP3 and AAC streams, not to their Opus streams.

Thank you in advance!

These are the links to the streams:

Deutschlandfunk Opus
64 kbit/s:
https://st01.sslstream.dlf.de/dlf/01/high/opus/stream.opus?aggregator=web
24 kbit/s:
https://st01.sslstream.dlf.de/dlf/01/low/opus/stream.opus?aggregator=web

Deutschlandfunk Kultur Opus
64 kbit/s:
https://st02.sslstream.dlf.de/dlf/02/high/opus/stream.opus?aggregator=web
24 kbit/s:
https://st02.sslstream.dlf.de/dlf/02/low/opus/stream.opus?aggregator=web

Deutschlandfunk Nova Opus
64 kbit/s:
https://st03.sslstream.dlf.de/dlf/03/high/opus/stream.opus?aggregator=web
24 kbit/s:
https://st03.sslstream.dlf.de/dlf/03/low/opus/stream.opus?aggregator=web